# Correctly Bind keys from appsettings to class in NET Core 7

Tags: c#, .net-core, configuration, asp.net-core-7.0

In older versions of .NET Core you house any global settings in a Startup cs file, but from what I know in .NET Core 7+ you house them in a program cs file which structurally looks different - hence why this may looks like a duplicate question.

My aim is to bind keys from the app settings json file to a class during runtime. Providing that the values in the app settings json file and the class you should be able to bind them 1:1 when you are injecting the class in a constructor and attempting to read the values.

I cant seem to get it to bind unfortunately. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

My attempt looks like this in the program.cs file:

```
builder.Configuration.Bind(new AuthenticationConfiguration());

builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationConfiguration>();
```

My appsettings .json file looks like this:

```
"Authentication": {
  "AccessTokenSecret": "somekey",
  "AccessTokenExpirationMinutes": "35",
  "Issuer": "https://test.com:1234/",
  "Audience": "https://test:1234/"
}
```

My class looks like this:

```
public class AuthenticationConfiguration
{
    public string AccessTokenSecret { get; set; }
    public int AccessTokenExpirationMinutes { get; set; }
    public string Issuer { get; set; }
    public string Audience { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I also tried out: 

builder.Services.AddOptions<AuthenticationConfiguration>()
    .Bind(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Authentication"));
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationConfiguration>();

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

I had to use refer to the IOptions Services in my program cs file

```
builder.Services.AddOptions<AuthenticationConfiguration>()
.Bind(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Authentication"));
builder.Services.AddSingleton(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<AuthenticationConfiguration>>().Value);
```